# How do I refer to a jquery object through a function parameter?

Tags: jquery, function, object

I have a var called testItem and want to add to the 'amount' inside it. I've set up a function so if you pass through the id and amount it should pick up on which variable you're referring to, except it doesn't work:

```
function addItem(id, count){
    id.amount = id.amount + count;
}

var testItem = {
    amount: 0,
};

addItem("testItem",100);

alert(testItem.amount);
```

How do I refer to testItem.amount by using the 'id' parameter? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable) (Hint: For global variables, `window` is the object they are properties of.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed testItem as string instead of variable name.

```js
function addItem(id, count) {
  id.amount += count;
}

var testItem = {amount: 0};
addItem(testItem, 100);

alert(testItem.amount);
```